# How can you listen for a click event, but NOT a touch event in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, touch

I have an application where I have "cards" representing items in the store. On a device with a mouse (desktop, laptop) I have a hover event that shows a few more details, and presents a button to click. The whole card can be clicked, however, to go to that item's detail page. On a touch-enabled device, however, there is no way to show that hover state. Is there a way in angular's click event to determine if the event originated as a touch event so that I can disable the click action?

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to check the event in your bind directly:

```
if(event.touches){
    //touchy
}
else{
    //no touchy
}
```

Comment: I assume that to use this I have to have [ngTouch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch) included?

Comment: I cannot get this to work. `$event` does not have a `touches` property. Can you provide a fiddle, jsbin, or codepin with example.